# How make transparent AppCompat style?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-appcompat

My activity style must be from AppCompat theme.

So I make custom style and set activity style in manifest.

But black background is shown.

Below is custom theme

```
<style name="TransparentTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="background">@null</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**use @android:color/transparent instead of @null**

Comment: It works <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

Comment: After adding this `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>` it is still not transparent. Adding `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` will help to make it transparent :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `#99000000` in background instead of null